# civibuild create permission error

Tags: civibuild

Running this:

```
civibuild create marc --type drupal-demo --url http://marc.localhost
```

Gives me this:

```
...
#33 /home/civicrm/buildkit/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(16): drush_main()
#34 {main}
    [is_error] => 1
    [error_message] => DB Error: unknown error
)

+++ drush scr /home/civicrm/buildkit/src/drush/perm.php
Could not find the permission: register to volunteer                                                                                    [error]
Could not find the permission: register to volunteer                                                                                    [error]
civicrm@civicrm-dev-vb:~/buildkit/build
```

Answer (score 1):

This is https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-299

The workaround documented there works.

1. Connect to your MySql server as root
2. Run these two statements

   SET sql_mode = '';
   SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
3. Try again